# Issue with magento "add to cart" button on Home Page

Tags: magento, checkout

I am facing an issue with  magento add to cart on **home page**.When i click add to cart sometimes it redirecting to **shopping cart is empty** page.But working fine in product page.

I disabled ajax cart option in admin side.

Comment: What theme are you using? Can you turn on template hints and post the template the contains the add to cart action?

Comment: i am using **mt-fornax**